# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null in our java script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

since Our Javascript code was working fine. now we are facing that

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at tick (run_current_time.js:39)
```

script issue in our web applications.

```
 document.getElementById('time_ticker').innerHTML = transformMiliseconds(newd-d);
```

By default, the form will be loaded in the first tab. actually the problem we are unable to switch over other tabs. when we click the other tab then it will be loaded and active only our default tab. we are unable to switch over other tabs.

Comment: seems no such element with this `id`.Please share the html markup

Comment: I think issue is 'time_tiker' can not be found in you html page

Comment: Can you post your html as well? As others said you might want to start looking at the issue by checking if 'time_ticker' exists or not

Comment: may be you kept the script file above <body>, which call the function even before dom is constructed and that causes the error. Try to keep document.getElementById('time_ticker').innerHTML = transformMiliseconds(newd-d) in <script>  after <body> tag

Answer (score 0):

At the time the script runs, it’s not finding any element with that ID. To prevent the error, you could do a null check before trying to set the innerHTML, like so:

```
   var ticker = document.getElementById(“time_ticker”);
   if (ticker !== null) ticker.innerHTML = transformMiliseconds(newd-d);
```

However, this might not solve your problem — it will simply prevent the null reference error from occurring.

Is the time ticker element being created by a script? It could be that the time ticker element only being added to the DOM *after* this innerHTML assignment script is run.